# Template specialization vs. default values

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae

I've seen a template written this way:

```
    template<typename T, bool = is_integral<T>::value, bool = is_floating_point<T>::value>
    struct helper {};

    template<typename T>
    struct helper<T, true, false>
    {
        typedef TypeAppropriateForThisSpecialization type;
    };
```

and then used

```
typename helper<T>::type t;
```

What does it mean? Does it mean that there is a specialization for the `true`-`false` combination of template type params that, if they're ommited, get evaluated by `is_integral` and `is_floating_point` ?

Is this the same? (this is a variable declaration/definition):

```
typename helper<T, true, false>::type t;

typename helper<T, is_integral<T>::value, is_floating_point<T>::value>::type t;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it mean? Does it mean that there is a specialization for the
>   true-false combination of template type params that, if they're
>   ommited, get evaluated by is_integral and is_floating_point ?

The idea behind the code is to either select the specialization where type is defined, or the other (where type is not defined).

If the user of the helper does not specify the default template parameters. The specialization shall be selected if type T is an integral and not a floating point value, else the non-specialized template shall be selected.

> Is this the same? (this is a variable declaration/definition):
>
> ```
> typename helper<T, true, false>::type t;
> typename helper<T, is_integral<T>::value, is_floating_point<T>::value>::type t;
> ```

The above mentioned type definitions would have the same result if T is indeed integral and not a floating point, else they would have a different result (in which case ::type may be invalid).

This type of code might be used in SFINAE. See [more c++ idioms - enable if](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/enable-if) as example. You can also look at boost::enable_if. It would be good if you can give us an example of usage.

This (idiom) would be used to select a different function in an overload set based on an attribute of T, and not the type only (see example below for similar usage of enable_if).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type foo( T )
{
  std::cout << "T is a float" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_integral<T>::value &&
  std::is_unsigned<T>::value>::type foo( T )
{
  std::cout << "T is integral and unsigned" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<
 std::is_integral<T>::value &&
 std::is_signed<T>::value>::type foo( T )
{
  std::cout << "T is integral and signed" << std::endl;
}

template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<
 !(std::is_integral<T>::value || std::is_floating_point<T>::value)>::type
 foo( T )
{
  std::cout << "T is neiter integral nor float" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  foo( 10u );
  foo( 10 );
  foo( 10.2 );
  foo( std::string() );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is really nice, one thing that I'd like to see is the process of instantiating e.g. `helper<int>::type` - what exactly does the compiler do? *Because how I understand is that it fills the two missing types with values coming from is_integral and is_floating_point and then checks whether a specialization for those types exists.. right?*

Comment: If there are no template arguments (the value substituted for a template parameter) specified, the compiler shall derive the "actual template arguments" from the "default template parameters". Therefore the default template parameters (is_integral etc) only have an effect if the client/instantiator of the template does not specify his own arguments, in which case a different specialization may be selected based on the type of T.

Comment: This type of code is typically used to select different function (from an overload set), based on a common attribute of the type T, and not the type (T) alone... Therefore, e.g: select this function overload for all types T that are integers and not floats.

Comment: Ok, I almost get it; what confuses me is that the compiler `a)` generates the default types based on the general template `b)` then finds a specialized template for the default types just generated. Am I right here?

Comment: The non specialized template definition applies to all specializations, therefore the default template-arguments (associated with it) are considered during all template instantiations (when no arguments are specified explicitly).

Comment: Therefore, the compiler at point of template instantiation considers whether explicit arguments exist. If not, then it considers all default arguments from all template declarations in scope (C++ Std 11 14.1 par 10). After the actual template arguments are selected, the applicable specialization is realized/chosen, yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
typename helper<T>::type t;
typename helper<T, is_integral<T>::value, is_floating_point<T>::value>::type t;
```

Are the same.

and helper<T, true, false> is specialized (so when T is a integral but not a floating point when used in helper<T>).